# Stream.Read is combining two different reads

Tags: c#, client, client-server, filestream

i have a simplistic file server\client application ive written in c#. but i commonly run into the problem that my stream writes two different reads into a single buffer. i have a synchronized stream, still isnt helping. any suggestions? thanks!

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
receive_fspos = new byte[30];
int bytesread = stream_1.Read(receive_fspos, 0, receive_fspos.Length);//this is where it gets combined
if (bytesread == 0) 
{ 
    finished = true; 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25); 
}
string string_1 = utf.GetString(receive_fspos).TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)0 });
int fsposition = (int)Convert.ToInt64(string_1);
bytestosend = fsposition;
filestream.Position = fsposition;
byte[] buffer_1 = new byte[bufsize];
int bytesreadfromfs = filestream.Read(buffer_1, 0, buffer_1.Length);
stream_1.Write(buffer_1, 0, buffer_1.Length);
Console.Write("\rSent " + fsposition + " / " + length + " bytes");
finished = true;
```

Comment: Are you saying that, for example, you write two messages of 10 bytes each to a stream and receive 20 bytes at the other end?  That's why it's called a stream.  The bytes that go in one end come out the other in the same order, without duplication or loss.  There is no concept of an entity larger than a byte, i.e. a _message_ or _record_.  The number of bytes received in a read depends on buffering throughout the network.  If you write a total of 100 bytes you could get 43 from the first read, 56 from the next and then a lone byte.

Comment: not exactly. I have set the length of each read to oh let's say 30 bytes and each message is actually 8 bytes, its writing two of the server's stream.write() calls to the buffer in one call of the stream.read() method. it should not do this, it should write the 8 byte message and 22 blank bytes to one 30 byte buffer. right?

Comment: Sorry, but a read will retrieve all of the available data up to the size of the buffer.  Any remaining bytes in the buffer will not be affected, i.e. cleared.  If you want to interpret the stream of bytes as messages then _you_ need to create a way to determine the boundaries of each message.  I have used a header where the first 2 or 4 bytes contain the length of the message.  Additional header fields may contain message type, subtype, id, ... .  Since bytes are received in groups of any size you must be prepared to reassemble messages from fragments.  Even the length field can be fragmented!

Comment: haha i was afraid of this, only reason to use UDP is the unspecified receive length. i will think of something thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working, code > 30000 chars :\
it is a little messy but hey, it's functional.

server : https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wyccxpjbja10z3/Program.cs?m

client : https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp78nx4ubacsz6f/Program.cs?m

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend writing your own stream method if you do not fully understand it.

The problem that you are having is because the incoming data is a stream of bytes that does not give you a way of knowing how many bytes in length that the message is.

In the code below you are stating that you would like to read "receive_fspos.Length" bytes of the stream. Since "receive_fspos.Length" is 30, the amount of bytes that will be read will be anywhere from 0 to 30.

If there is only 15 bytes that have been received by the connection. It will give you 15 bytes. If the message was 20 bytes long. Then the message is now split up into different segments.

If the first message was 4 bytes and the second message is 12 bytes. Now you have 2 messages and a set of 16 blank bytes at the end. Even worse those 16 "blank" bytes could be the beginning of a third message coming in to the stream.

If the message is 50 bytes long. Then you will only receive half of the message. Now you would need to add the bytes that were read to a seperate buffer. Read from the stream again. Then repeat this until you have determined that you have read the exact amount of bytes that are needed to complete the entire message. Then concat all of the read bytes back to a single byte[].

```
     receive_fspos = new byte[30];
     int bytesread = stream_1.Read(receive_fspos, 0, receive_fspos.Length);//this is where it gets combined
```

Instead of rolling your own loop please use the BCL methods. It sounded like you are using strings so this would be the preferred method.. I would suggest the following.

```
using(NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
{
     networkStream.ReadTimeout = timeout; //Set a timeout to stop the stream from reading indefinately           

     //To receive a string
     string incomingString = stream.ReadLine();

     //To send a string
     stream.WriteLine(messageToSend);
     stream.Flush();
}
```

Your answer clarified that you are trying to send a file. For this I would recommend sending an array of bytes[]. Using this method you can send anything that can be serialized. This includes a file. Please note that the size of the file is limited since it must be kept in memory. To write a larger file you would want to save the data in chunks as it is being streamed in.

```
//Please note that if the file size is large enough. It may be preferred to use a stream instead of holding the entire file in memory.
byte[] fileAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

using(NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
using(BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(networkStream))
using(BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(networkStream))
{
     networkStream.ReadTimeout = timeout; //Set a timeout to stop the stream from reading indefinately           

     //To receive a byte array
     int incomingBytesLength = BinaryReader.ReadInt32(); //The header is 4 bytes that lets us know how large the incoming byte[] is.
     byte[] incomingBytes = BinaryReader.ReadBytes(incomingBytesLength);

     //To send a byte array
     BinaryWriter.Write(fileAsBytes.Length); //Send a header of 4 bytes that lets the listener know how large the incoming byte[] is.
     BinaryWriter.Write(fileAsBytes);
}
```

Comment: In my code I have set it up so that the bytes that are read from the server are written to the file as soon as received. thank you for your answer, this method looks a lot more stable than my currently used one. I will try this ASAP and get back with you.  thanks.

Comment: hmmmm... nothing appears to be happening, i'm using the send and receive methods you have posted. nothing is being sent.

Comment: Did you create a TcpClient and TcpListener? Be sure that you have a Tcp connection before using this method.

Comment: int length3 = 30 - fsposition.ToString().Length;
string s1 = fsposition.ToString() + new string('x', length3);
fsposbyte = utf.GetBytes(s1);
stream_1.Write(fsposbyte, 0, fsposbyte.Length);

Comment: server receives 30 bytes and simply replaces the "x" with "". then converts that into an int. its not solving the problem its just patching it up.

Comment: First, you should not be formatting your string to fit a length. Secondly, you are trying to create your own streaming algorithm. Please use either of the two provided above. It works for both server and client.